# using grep in a script which prompt user for input

Tags: bash, ksh

I have written one shell script which ask for some username and password from standart input.
Once username and password is typed there is a output depending upon the parameters passed in the script.

Say my script name is **XYZ.ksh.**

Now my problem is that users of these script want to use want to use this script in conjugation with other shell commands like *grep, less, more, wc etc.*

Normally yes they can use

```
XYZ.ksh | grep abc
```

But in my case since XYZ is prompting for username and password we are not able to use "|" in front of that. It blocks forever.

I just wanted to know how can I implement the functinality.

**What I tried**
I tried taking input of "more commands " from user where user types things like "| grep abc"
but when i used this input in my script it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<<<` like this:

```
XYZ.ksh <<< "your inputs" | grep abc
```

Comment: yes i thought of this but the problem is I do not want user to type the password, it should not be visible that is why I am prompting user for the password in the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you can test to see if stdout is connected to a terminal with:

```
if [[ -t 1 ]]
```

That way you can supress the prompt if the output is not going to the console.
Alternatively, with your "more commands" solution, run the command connected to a named pipe.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions commonly used for this kind of problem but none of them is perfect :

- Read password from standard input. It makes it really hard to use the script in pipes. This method is used by commands that deal with changing passwords : `passwd`, `smbpasswd`
- Provide username and password in the command line parameters. This solution is good for using the script in pipes, but command line can be viewed by anyone, using `ps -ef` for exemple. This is used by `mysql`, `htpasswd`, `sqlplus`, ...
- Store username and password unencrypted in a file in user's home directory. This solution is good for using the script in pipes, but the script must check if the file is visible or modifiable by other users. This is used by `mysql`
- Store private key in local file and public key in distant file, as used by SSH. You must have a good encryption knowledge to do this correctly (or rely on SSH), but it's excellent for use in pipes, even creating pipes accross different machines !
- Don't deal with passwords, and assume that if a user is logged in in the system, he has the right to run the program. You may give execute privilege only to one group to filter who can use the program. This is used by `sqlplus` from Oracle, VirtualBox, games on some Linux distributions, ...

My preferred solution would be the last, as the system is certainly better than any program I could write with regard to security.

If the password is used to login to some other service, then I would probably go for the private file containing the password.

Answer (score 0):

One less-than-optimal possibility is to display the prompt to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

```
echo -n "Username:" >/dev/stderr
```

A better solution would be to check `stdin` of the shell. If it's a terminal, then open it for writing and redirect to that file. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do that in bash or ksh; perhaps something like

```
echo -n "Username:" >/dev/tty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (I assume you are reading username and password in your script with `read`)

```
(
    read -p "user:" USER
    read -p "pass:" PASS
) < /dev/tty > /dev/tty
```

and you'll be able to run

```
$ cmd | XYZ.ksh
```

However, I agree with other answers: just don't ask for user and password and give the correct permissions to the script to allow access.